# Is it possible for a Crystal macro to determine if it's being called inside a block?

Tags: crystal-lang

Is it possible for a Crystal macro to determine if it is rendering inside a block vs. outside of it?

```
macro my_macro
  {% if inside_a_block? %}
     break if do_something
  {% else %}
     return if do_something
  {% end %}
end

my_func do
  my_macro
end

class A
  def a
    my_macro
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. By the way, you may have block in a method, what do you expect in this case?

Comment: Could you please describe the task you are trying to solve with this?